# HTML Agility Pack SocketException when deployed

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-3.1

I am not sure if this is related to HTML Agility but here's my problem.

I am parsing an HTML Document using the HTML Agility Pack as below:

```
var web = new HtmlWeb();
var doc = web.Load(url);
...
Parsing Logic
```

This works perfectly fine when I am running it locally, however, when I deployed my application I get the following errors: (I am hosting using Ionos 1&1)

```
SocketException: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.
```

System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.ConnectAsync(string host, int port, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

and

`HttpRequestException: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.
System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.ConnectAsync(string host, int port, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask<TResult>.get_Result()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredValueTaskAwaitable<TResult>+ConfiguredValueTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.ConnectAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, bool allowHttp2, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask<TResult>.get_Result()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredValueTaskAwaitable<TResult>+ConfiguredValueTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.CreateHttp11ConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask<TResult>.get_Result()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredValueTaskAwaitable<TResult>+ConfiguredValueTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.GetHttpConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask<TResult>.get_Result()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredValueTaskAwaitable<TResult>+ConfiguredValueTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, bool doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
System.Net.Http.DiagnosticsHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
System.Net.Http.HttpClient.FinishSendAsyncUnbuffered(Task<HttpResponseMessage> sendTask, HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationTokenSource cts, bool disposeCts)
System.Net.HttpWebRequest.SendRequest()
System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()`

and

`System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (10060): A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.
   at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.ConnectAsync(String host, Int32 port, CancellationToken cancellationToken)`

It might also be the case that outgoing calls from my Web Application are blocked from Ionos 1&1 for security reasons?

I can access the link from any browser perfectly fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve the issue. 
As I was suspected (since the code is running fine locally), there was nothing wrong with the HTML Agility Pack.
The Issue was the outgoing calls from my Web App were blocked from my hosting provider.

To solve the issue, I had to use a proxy to make the call.
The proxy details (address and port) are usually provided by the hosting.

Hope this helps other people in the future.